# domain/machine$ login failed error on debugging in visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, iis-8

I am not able to access database through visual studio.
I am getting an error domain/machine$ login failed error on debugging in visual studio.I had set Windows Authentication as "Enable" in IIS.
I think it should use my credentials for login.Instead it is using my machine name. Please help .

Comment: show complete error message

Comment: That means that your windows account is not configured for delegation. Instead of passing your account to server, the program passes it's own name, and as it's running under localsystem it goes in network under domain/machine$  name

Comment: How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/